# Convert empty list to java list

Tags: scala, list

In the documentation on `Nil` to empty `java.util.List<String>`. I tried this:

```
Nil.asJava
```

But it refuses to compile. So I did the following:

```
Nil.asInstanceOf[Seq[String]].asJava
```

and it worked. But it seems hacky to me... Maybe there another way to do that?

Comment: compiles just fine for me. please provide the full error that compiler produces.

Comment: also keep in mind that Nil is defined as `Nil extends List[Nothing]`

Answer (score 4):

```
scala> import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.JavaConverters._

scala> Nil.asJava
res1: java.util.List[A] = []

scala> List[String]().asJava
res2: java.util.List[String] = []
```

Comment: in that case, you can add one more: `(Nil:List[String]).asJava`

Answer (score 1):

As per Scala 2.13 `import collection.JavaConverters._` is obsolete, use `import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._` instead.

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

Nil.asJava
res0: java.util.List[Nothing] = []

List[String]().asJava
res1: java.util.List[String] = []

val a = List[String]().asJava
a: java.util.List[String] = []
```

Please note this `java.util.List[String]` is immutable as `a` is too. (There can nothing be done with it.)